# MIMEText - Object has no attribute 'encode' (SMTP)

Tags: python-3.x, mime

I'm trying to make my pi send email about it's IP via Gmail, based on [this link](https://elinux.org/RPi_Email_IP_On_Boot_Debian).

From what I've read in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output) I should be getting string output of shell in 'output1' variable when using .stdout.decode(). But unlike usual strings like 'Hello World' - Which show no error in MIMEText() - MIMEText(output1) shows following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/upload/startup_mail.py", line 24, in <module>
    message = MIMEText(output1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/mime/text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'CompletedProcess' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Can someone explain why Shell output always lack 'encode' attribute despite decoding it into 'us-ascii', and how to properly handle Shell output to MIMEText()?

---

Source Code as Follows:

```
import subprocess
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import datetime

to = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
user = 'xxx@gmail.com'
us_p = 'xxxx'

smtpserv = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
smtpserv.ehlo()
smtpserv.starttls()
smtpserv.ehlo()
smtpserv.login(user, us_p)

# run command in background console and get output
output1 = subprocess.run(['ip', 'route', 'list'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output1.stdout.decode('us-ascii')

today = datetime.date.today()

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message = MIMEText(output1)
msg.attach(message)
msg['Subject'] = 'Pi Booted on %s' % today.strftime('%b %d %Y')

smtpserv.sendmail(user, [to], msg.as_string())
smtpserv.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement `output1.stdout.decode('us-ascii')` does not have any effect. It decodes the output, but the result is never stored. In the line `message = MIMEText(output1)` you pass the result of `subprocess.run()`, which is an object of type `CompletedProcess`. You should have passed the decoded text instead. So:

```py
decoded_output = output1.stdout.decode('us-ascii')
message = MIMEText(decoded_output)
```

Comment: If you only have a single body part, there is no need to wrap it in a multipart container. Like the name implies, multipart containers are useful when you have multiple parts.

Comment: I'm really sorry for late reply! I didn't know I had to assign decoded value to variable, it works now flawlessly. Since I lack reputation my vote up won't show up but I surely did. Thanks for help! :)